# In scala 2.13, why implicit scope of a companion object may sometimes be misaligned? How to correct it?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, companion-object

The following is a simple example that tests the implicit feature of the scala 2.13 compiler:

```
object OverridingScope {

  trait System {

    trait Handler[T]
  }

  object Sys1 extends System {

    object Handler {

      implicit def handle1: Handler[Int] = new Handler[Int] {}
    }

    implicit def handle2: Handler[Long] = new Handler[Long] {}
  }
}
```

According this article:

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

The companion object of the trait `Handler` can be automatically imported as part of the implicit scope when type `Handler[_]` is used, the outer object `Sys1` should be irrelevant. This means handle1 should be visible and handle2 should be hidden.

But the following test case shows the exact opposite:

```
class OverridingScope extends BaseSpec {

  import OverridingScope._

  it("implicits in companion is in scope") {

//    val hh = implicitly[Sys1.Handler[Int]]
    // Doesn't work
  }

  it("implicits in outer object is in scope") {

    val hh = implicitly[Sys1.Handler[Long]]
    // Should NOT work
  }
}
```

Considering that Handler is both a class & object name, the fact that handle1 doesn't work looks highly suspicious. Also, I've checked the full list of implicit import:

```
First look in current scope
Implicits defined in current scope
Explicit imports
wildcard imports
Same scope in other files
Now look at associated types in
Companion objects of a type
Implicit scope of an argument's type (2.9.1)
Implicit scope of type arguments (2.8.0)
Outer objects for nested types
Other dimensions
```

None of the above can explain why handle2 is in the scope. What could be the reasons?

BTW: For those who dismissed implicit as a important scala feature: Implicit is the only way to implement type class, and if you want to implement it with minimal boilerplate, sometimes the above pattern can be the only choice.

Comment: `object Handler` does not appear to be the companion object of `trait Handler[T]`.

Comment: More precisely, it isn't the companion object because it's defined in a different scope and the specification says: "Generally, a companion module of a class is an object which has the same name as the class and **is defined in the same scope** and compilation unit. Conversely, the class is called the companion class of the module."

Comment: "None of the above can explain why handle2 is in the scope" Why do you think "Outer objects for nested types" doesn't explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Point 3 [here](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/implicit-resolution.html) explains that implicits/givens in prefixes of the type in question contribute to its implicit scope (in Scala 3 not if it's a package). So for the type `Sys1.Handler[Long]` implicits in `Sys1` are in the implicit scope because `Sys1` is a non-package prefix.

`handle1` is not in the implicit scope because object `Handler` in object `Sys1` is not the companion object of trait `Handler` in trait `System`.

Comment: Is that a dotty document? I'm not using dotty

Comment: Yes but the only thing that should be different is the rule that the prefix can't be a package in Scala 3.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I forgot the 'Outer objects for nested types'. Thanks a lot!